# How to fill a ListView with a string-array?

Tags: android

I want to show these itens at my ListView

```
<string-array name="bookmark_titles">
    <item>Google</item>
    <item>Bing</item>
    <item>Gmail</item>
</string-array>
```

I have a method that gets these values.

```
public static Collection getBookmarks(Context context) {
    Collection bookmarks = new Collection();

    String[] titles  = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bookmark_titles);

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i ++) {
        bookmarks.add(titles[i]);
    }

    return bookmarks;
}
```

How can I call the method getBookmarks in my main.java to fill the ListView?

I have already created a ListView. It is:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#ECECEC"
    android:dividerHeight="1sp" />
```

main.java
I am trying to do something like this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_listView);

ArrayList<Bookmark> my_array = BookmarkCollection.getTestBookmarks(context);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, my_array);    
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create your adapter with a one liner, check out the static method  [ArrayAdapter createFromResource(Context context, int textArrayResId, int textViewResId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#createFromResource%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29)

The first argument will probably be your Activity, the second is `R.array.bookmark_titles`, and the third is a layout to use.

To clarify based on the comments, the method accepts `int`, which is exactly what the constants in your generated `R` class are stored as.

Here's a complete example, assuming this is being called from an Activity:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.bookmark_titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
myListView.setAdapter(aa);
```

In this case, `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` refers to an XML layout that is provided by the Android SDK.  You can change this if needed.

Comment: And then attach the return value from `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()` to the ListView with `lv.setAdapter()`.

Comment: I will try. I am using the ArrayAdapter() method, but it is not working.

Comment: textArrayResId The identifier of the array to use as the data source.
textViewResId The identifier of the layout used to create views.
What this mean? They are int. Where I get these values? Thank you.

Comment: See my updated answer, I attempted to clarify the int parameters.

Comment: By this way it works properly. Thank you. But just another question. Inside my Collection class I have the getBookmarks() method. Can I do the same thing using this method?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an ArrayAdapter and have it use either an Array or a List to give it data

```
lv.setAdatper(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.some_layout_to_use, R.id.some_textview_in_layout, listData);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand. Could you give an example, please? My code, now, contains a way that I am trying to do. Thank you!