# Android studio array generation

Tags: java, android

Hello I have a program which creates a random string every 3 seconds
After generating string I want to save it and show all strings in a listview
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save it permanently you should read about SQLiteDatabases in Android.

If it can be deleted after you app closes you can just store it in a member variable. See here for some hints: [How to fill a ListView with a string-array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069685/how-to-fill-a-listview-with-a-string-array)

Answer (score 0):

create ArrayList

```
        ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(subject));
```

then Add the String to ArrayList

```
        itemList.add("your String");
```

use the below code to show them as list

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, simple_list_item_1, itemList);
    ListView listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    listV.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You got planty of storage options when working with Android.

> Android provides several options for you to save persistent
>   application data. The solution you choose depends on your specific
>   needs, such as whether the data should be private to your application
>   or accessible to other applications (and the user) and how much space
>   your data requires.
>
> Your data storage options are the following:
>
> Shared Preferences Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
>   Internal Storage Store private data on the device memory. External
>   Storage Store public data on the shared external storage. SQLite
>   Databases Store structured data in a private database. Network
>   Connection Store data on the web with your own network server.

Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).